# Type Mismatch occuring only once in online file

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below, I run through a code several times depending on a number of entries in a table. In this case, it's 4. If I run the code, it gives a error 13 type mismatch the first time on a certain loop. So it'll give one when a = 1. But then the next time when I run one, it won't give an error on a = 1, but it will on a = 2. So I have to run the code 4 times and then it actually gives the result I want.

When I put some MsgBoxes to check where the problem was located, it was situated somewhere around the TopicCount calculation with the following formula `TopicCount = [TopicAmount].Cells(a, 1)`

These documents are located on SharePoint and when I download them and run them locally, they don't give any error. So I suppose it has something to do with the path, but I can't locate the issue.

If there is any information missing or you have additional questions, don't hesitate.

Any interest and help would be highly appreciated, thank you so much.

**EDIT1**: To make it even weirder, I followed the tip of Greedo and used F9 and F8 to go through the code step by step. When I tap on F8 slowly when it comes to the TopicCount, it works perfectly throughout the entire code. When I hold F8 down instead of tapping it, I get the type mismatch error.

Cheers,
Bart

```
Sub PullValue()

Dim path As String, file As String, sheet As String, sheet2 As String, TableName As String
Dim LastRow As Long, SectionCount As Long, StatusCount As Long, TopicCount As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False


Worksheets("Consolidation").Cells.ClearContents

With Worksheets("Hidden").ListObjects("TopicAmount")

    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
    .ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

End With

With Worksheets("Sections").ListObjects("Sections")

    SectionCount = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - _
    Application.CountBlank(.DataBodyRange)

End With

With Worksheets("Settings").ListObjects("Status")

    StatusCount = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - _
    Application.CountBlank(.DataBodyRange)

End With

For a = 1 To SectionCount

    With Worksheets("Consolidation")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    If LastRow <> 1 Then

        LastRow = LastRow + 2

    End If

    Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = [Sections].Cells(a, 1)

    path = Application.ThisWorkbook.path + "/"
    file = Worksheets("Consolidation").Cells(LastRow, 1)
    sheet = "Overview"
    sheet2 = "Hidden"

    Worksheets("Hidden").ListObjects("TopicAmount").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

    [TopicAmount].Cells(a, 1) = "='" & path & "[" & file & ".xlsm]" & _
            sheet2 & "'!" & Cells(1, 4).Address & ""

    TopicCount = [TopicAmount].Cells(a, 1)

    For i = LastRow + 1 To LastRow + TopicCount + 1

        For j = 1 To StatusCount + 1

            Cells(i, j).Formula = "='" & path & "[" & file & ".xlsm]" & _
            sheet & "'!" & Cells(i - LastRow, j).Address & ""

        Next j

    Next i

    Worksheets("Consolidation").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(LastRow + 1, 1), Cells(LastRow + TopicCount + 1, _
    StatusCount + 1)), , xlYes).Name = [Sections].Cells(a, [Sections[Sections]].Column)

    TableName = [Sections].Cells(a, 1)
    Worksheets("Consolidation").ListObjects(TableName).TableStyle = "Testing Progress"
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).AutoFilter

Next a


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer; but when looking for bugs in your code, another good way is to *step through* it - that is, press `F8` to run your code line by line. This will allow you to find the exact line causing the error. If your code is long, and you know sections of it are valid, you can insert breakpoints at the end of those sections (either by typing `Stop`, or hitting `F9` when you have a particular line of code selected). Then when you run your code with `F5`, it will stop at these locations and you can then step through from there (`F8`) or run from there (`F5`)

Comment: Thanks, Greedo, that's a lot faster than writing MsgBoxes everywhere. Much appreciated comment!

Comment: If your intention in `Dim i, j, a As Integer` is to declare each of those variables to be an `Integer`, you have failed. Only `a` is declared to be an integer, the others are variants. In any event, why use `Integer` at all? On modern machines, there is no real reason to use it rather than `Long`. You are just risking overflow errors with no corresponding gain.

Comment: As you can see, I haven't done a lot of programming in my life. Thanks for the tip, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Where exactly does the Error apear? Dosn't it show it if you press Dubuger und the Error MEssage?

Comment: When I press down F8 to let it go through the code fast, it stops at the line with

TopicCount = [TopicAmount].Cells(a, 1)

It doesn't give me a debug option. I can only press OK or Help.

Comment: Is there definitely something in TopicAmount when the code reaches that point as that line refers to a cell in the body area?

Comment: Hi SJR, I tried to check if something is in it when the code reaches the TopicCount line. For a split second, there is a #REF! and then it changes to the right value. It seems like the file needs time to get the value from the other document. This might actually be it!

Answer (score 0):

From your Comment i got, that the Problem since to be with the Reference.
That it will not be Updated Fast enough.

So here is a Solution:

You can use the `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` just to wait a Second and give Excel Time to Update the Reference.

If you wan't to do it a bit Preatier, you could use the `IsError()` Function Like this.

```
If IsError(TopicCount ) Then'When #Ref! Wait for 1 Second    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    DoEvents
End If
```

Or you could do the same in a Loop and Check after Every Second if the Value is set Corectly.

---

**Old Answer**

I think that the Problem is, that there is a Number Formated as String in this cell. So you will get a type dismatch because you can not insert a string into a long Variable.

you can try to convert the string to a Long like this:

```
TopicCount = CLng([TopicAmount].Cells(a, 1))
```

---

And secondly i would Deklare the VAriables like John Coleman said:

```
 Dim path As String, file As String, sheet As String, sheet2 As String, TableName As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, SectionCount As Long, StatusCount As Long, TopicCount As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer
    Dim Rng1 As Range
```

Beacuse:
`Dim yxz, abc as Integer` is the equivalent of:

```
Dim yxz
Dim abc as Integer
```

and that is the equivalent of:

```
Dim yxz as Variant
Dim abc as Date
```

Comment: While it couldn't hurt to use `CLng()`, it doesn't seem to explain the nature of the problem. I don't think that downloading the file would change the cell formatting, but OP reports that the file error doesn't occur when the file is downloaded.

Comment: I thought the same, but i had once the same Problem, that the Numbers were written with quotation marks, so Excel will use it as a string. So you need to Convert it to a Number. And of Curse it could be aswell, that the Range or Sheet Name does not exists. But i wanted to check first if Clng() would solve the Problem.

Comment: I've just tried to put CLng() around the code. Although it doesn't give me the error anymore, the TopicCount is the wrong value. It gives me back 2023 lines instead of 5. After the comment of SJR in one of the comments above, I believe that this is still caused by the #REF! that appears for a very short time. This would also explain why it does work when you go slowly through it step by step. And maybe also when doing it local because it can retrieve the values much easier.

Comment: The wait doesn't seem to solve it. I turned on ScreenUpdating so I can see better what's going on. When the application is waiting 1 second, it stays on #REF!. Even when the error pops up, the #REF! is still there. It only updates after I've clicked OK on the error box. As I said before, once the reference has been placed once and the error is clicked away, that number of the loop will work the next time even if I delete it.

Comment: @BartDeKleijn ok, what happen if you turn Alerts off with  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Comment: I still receive the Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch when turning off the alerts.